# Yii: How to translate app when using slugs?

Tags: php, yii

I have translated my app in 2 languages;

`romanian` and `english`;

the messages folder `ro_ro` for `romanian` and `en_us` for `english`;

these are the settings for the languages

```
'sourceLanguage'=> 'en_us',
'language' => 'en_us',
```

Yes, I know that the 2 values are identical and the setting is ignored;

the tricky part is that i want to use a `slug` as the `key` when trying to translate;

`Yii::t('some_table','unique_slug_something');`

I don't want to use it as:

`Yii::t('table_x','My Favorites');`

So, my app is not capable of translating to `en_us` language;

I must use the slugs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution:

```
'sourceLanguage'=>'00',
'language'=>'en',

protected/messages/de/app.php
protected/messages/en/app.php
protected/messages/fr/app.php
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/243/how-to-translate-and-do-the-translations-the-easy-way/

Comment: In order for Yii to translate a message, your `language` settings must be other than `sourceLanguage`. You ought to change the `sourceLanguage` to your native language code. Please mark your reply as answer as well.

Comment: yes i know what you are saying; i read the docs; but this is the way i needed my app to work: with slugs